# Return all Documents in XML DataBase

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, flower, sedna

in relational database we can query all tables like this:

```
select table_name from all_all_tables ;
```

or

```
select tname from tab;
```

How to return all xml files from Sedna XML database by using XQuery/XPath just as like we query tables in relational database ?

if I can use function where can I find a documentation for built-in XML Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.sedna.org/progguide/ProgGuidesu8.html#x14-580002.5.6 it sounds as if `$documents` gives you "all stand-alone documents, collections and in-collection documents".

Comment: thank you for replying, that is what I am looking for, I tried doc('$documents') it returns documents for system documents like $db_security_data and $modules. And also for user documents I built it. my question is can I control this by displaying only user documents ?

Comment: User documents don't start from '$'. So, XPath can be used for filtering: `doc('$documents')/documents/(document | collection)[not(starts-with(@name, '$'))]`